# my function won't iterate over each item and log them to the console

Tags: javascript

my function won't log all items to the console.

```
function myfunc(str){
   //return str.split('')[0].match(/[A-Z]/)
   console.log(str)
}
strings = ["hamza", "Hamza", "name", "Name"]
myfunc(...strings)
```

I've tried the spread operator and the apply function but both methods only log the first item. why does it not iterate over each item?

Comment: what's the output you expect?

Comment: i assumed it would iterate over each item to pass to the myFunc function as i've passed the array arguments to it using the spread operator and log them to the console however only the first item does.

Comment: `myfunc(...strings)` is the equivalent of calling `myfunc("hamza", "Hamza", "name", "Name")`, but `myfunc` only accepts a single string argument, the rest are ignored. Either make it accept an array of strings, or handle an arbitrary number of arguments using [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

Comment: ah okay, so spread operator doesn't pass the arguments to the function as if calling them individually, like the apply function does?

Comment: `apply()` doesn't call the function individually for each element, it simply calls the function with an array of arguments which are applied to the parameters of the function in order. Spread in this case is more similar to `call()`

Comment: perhaps you mean to call the function once for each element of the array? `for (const str of strings) myfunc(str);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function specified with a single parameter will always take single parameter. It cannot take more than that. You are spreading the `string` variable and it is passing the first element of the array to the function since it can only take one parameter.

If you have specified two parameters then spread operator would pass first two elements of the array.

If you want to spread the array, then just simply pass it to the function without spreading it. And then spread it inside the `console.log()`. For example:

```js
function myfunc(str) {
  console.log(...str);  // Spread here
}

let string = ["hamza", "Hamza", "name", "Name"];
myfunc(string);
```

Output:

```
hamza Hamza name Name
```

Or, if you want to print them in new lines. You could use `join()` method of **Array** data type. For example:

```js
function myfunc(str) {
  str = str.join("\n");
  console.log(str);
}

let string = ["hamza", "Hamza", "name", "Name"];
myfunc(string);
```

Output:

```
hamza
Hamza
name
Name
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see you are trying to use the `spread` operator while calling the function, but in that case, you need to use the `rest parameter` syntax if you want to catch all the arguments being passed to your function.
When you use a `spread` operator like this -

```
strings = ["hamza", "Hamza", "name", "Name"]
myfunc(...strings)
```

This is what it would do behind the scenes for all the values from the array -

```
strings = ["hamza", "Hamza", "name", "Name"]
myfunc(strings[0], strings[1], strings[2], strings[3]);
// OR
myfunc("hamza", "Hamza", "name", "Name");
```

If you have a fixed and small number of elements in the array you can do this -

```
function myfunc(arg1, arg1, arg3, arg4){
   console.log(arg1, arg1, arg3, arg4)
}
```

But if the number of arguments is not fixed then you can use the `rest operator`, the rest operator will catch all arguments being passed to function in an array.

```
function myfunc(...str){
   console.log(str)
}
strings = ["hamza", "Hamza", "name", "Name"]
myfunc(...strings)
```

**Rest parameters**

> The rest parameter syntax allows a function to accept an indefinite number of arguments as an array, providing a way to represent variadic functions in JavaScript.

Check this out for more details -

1. [Rest Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)
2. [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    console.log(str[i]);
}
```

Comment: im trying to understand the spread operator, im aware how to loop over an array using a for loop but appreciate the response.

Comment: The spread operator does not provide iteration, you sill still need to iterate as normal using a `for`, `for...of` or an array method.